# How to add kapt for local .jar files in KMM project

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, dagger, kapt

I am trying to add local .jar files in my KMM project and trying to access with kapt annotation processor. but getting error for following

> Unresolved reference : DaggerAppComponent

```
kapt(files("\\libs\\dagger_compiler_2.41.jar"))
kapt(files("\\libs\\dagger_android_processor_2.41.jar"))
```

[This is how added dagger related dependencies as local third party libraries]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlC0m.png)

Added .jar files in libs folder and tried to access it in build.gradle.kts but it gives unresolved reference.